# Application crashing without information about crash when transitioning to another view controller

Tags: swift, exception, crash, storyboard, swift4

I have two view controllers, `LoginViewController` and `TermsAndPrivacyViewController`.

On first view controller, there is a button that has `IBAction`, which opens `TermsAndPrivacyViewController`. On `TermsAndPrivacyViewController` I have web view, that loads url I am passing from `LoginViewController`. So, this is the code(Login view controller):

```
 @IBAction func tosAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: kTOSViewControllerIdentifier) as? TermsAndPrivacyViewController{

            vc.url =  URL(string: kTOSUrl)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

On TermsAndPrivacyViewController, I have this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        if let `url` = url {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        }
    }
```

So, when I hit a button, app crashes `SIGABRT` message, and nothing else. Also, I don't get any crash report on Firebase Crashlytics (I have detached an app from a debugger first, and produced a crash).

Now, the strange part :/ ... If I put a breakpoint on a first line of `tosAction()` method, and go step by step (or just let it continue), everything works normally. No crash???

Am I missing something obvious here? What is the reason of crashing? Also, I tried to put `Exception Breakpoint` but nothing changes. I only get this:

[image]

[image]

and a console:

[image: console image]

so, kinda no information about crash at all.

**EDIT**

Ok, now the even more strange part :) I just tried app on different phones.

App crashes on iPhone 6s+, iOS 12.1(16B5059d), but it works normally on iPhone 6, iOS 12.0 (16A366)

Comment: Is it crashing on LoginViewController page or in  TermsAndPrivacyViewController page ?

Comment: I was trying to figure out that, but when it crashes, it goes to first line of AppDelegate (see on pictures) at the moment I tap on a button (on LoginViewController). @BadrFilali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you use library or framework that not supported by those device.
you must see the error

did you try this?

when the app crashing, in the console press cmd+F and search exception.
now you can see your error

hope to helpful.

Comment: There is nothing in the console. I mean, almost nothing. It says: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: The same code works on other phones. It is very simple and standard code, that always worked. I wonder if it has something with timing...

Comment: you sure that you don't delete IBOutlet or Action without disconnecting form ViewController?
in the Main.storyboard right click on your ViewController & see you haven't any warning?

Comment: Nope. IBOutlet for a button, and its IBAction is there.

Comment: so just one things left. I think you use the framework or library that not supported on those device. read you're library's documentation.
 if it isn't really rum

Comment: I am using `WKWebView` to load a page from an url on `TermsAndServiceViewController`. It requires iOS 8.0+

Comment: Are you sure you are using simple UIWebView and not have something like WKWebView delegate? Most of time it will crash on  webView.navigationDelegate = self if you call  navigationDelegate on an onbject which has not this kind of property

Comment: so try this:

Select Target -> General -> Linked framework and libraries -> click on + symbol below -> search for webKit.Framwork -> add.

Comment: @AbbasTorabi Yeah, that was it. Gosh. After I added a framework, it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use segue methods inside your LoginViewController.

```
 @IBAction func tosAction(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToWeb", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

And call prepareForSegue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "GoToWeb") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! TermsAndPrivacyViewController
            vc.url = "YOUR_URL"
        }
```

And the code inside  TermsAndPrivacyViewController don't change

**Edit:**

Maybe your not binding well your UIButton, can you verify in the right panel, in the section "Show the connection inspector" if your button is call only once.

Comment: Oh I tried that too (just forgot to mention)... It crashes in a same way, no matter if I use segue or push a view controller :/

Comment: I would say all looks good. There is one IBAction and one IBOutlet for a button. As I said, it is strange that this code works good on every other phone, other than iPhone6s+...

Answer (score 0):

To get further information on this type of crashes, open the Breakpoints menu (or press CMD+8), click the plus icon in the bottom left corner and press *Exception Breakpoint...*. Right click, then edit. Add an action of the type *Debugger Command* and enter the following:

[image]

Reproduce the crash again, this time the console will output a more useful error message.